# Jenkins built to remote server

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have setup a jenkins job and it finishes with success. When I run the job, it picks code from Bitbucket, compiles it, put it Jenkins Workspaces but it never publishes it remote server. Here is my MSBuilt parameters:

MS Build File: `MyProject.csproj`

```
MS Build Command Line Arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="staging - test" /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:Configuration=Staging
```

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**